# Complex mysql query counting

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.6

I have 1 table name "companies" with several datas like :

| Id | Owner | Company | Job |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe | Company 1 | CEO |
| 1 | John Doe | Company 2 | CEO |
| 1 | John Doe | Company 3 | CEO |
| 1 | Gab Durand | Company 4 | CEO |
| 1 | Rob Dujn | Company 5 | CTO |
| 1 | Alex DoeMorse | Company 6 | COO |

What I need is to get 1 line by company with a row calculating the number of company own by each person.

This is my desired output :

| Id | Owner | Company | Job | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe | Company 1 | CEO | 3 |
| 1 | John Doe | Company 2 | CEO | 3 |
| 1 | John Doe | Company 3 | CEO | 3 |
| 1 | Gab Durand | Company 4 | CEO | 1 |
| 1 | Rob Dujn | Company 5 | CTO | 1 |
| 1 | Alex DoeMorse | Company 6 | COO | 1 |

What could be the mysql query?

EDIT : DB version 5.6.51

Thanks!

Comment: what's your DB version pre 8.0 or 8.0 ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please share more details. If you are using MySQL, then you are most probably **not** using v7, as this does not exist

Comment: My mistake, the mysql version is 5.6.51

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an extra column containing **analytic function** such as

```
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Id, owner) AS count
```

if DB version is `8.0`

As having a former DB version, prefer using **correlated subquery** such as

```
SELECT Id, Owner, company, Job,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM t 
         WHERE id = tt.id 
           AND Owner = tt.Owner ) AS count
  FROM t AS tt
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=275ee78e8cd9eef8caa60a6fef32638c)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
SELECT Owner, Job, count(Company) NoOfCompanies 
FROM   companies 
WHERE  Job='CEO' 
GROUP BY Owner,Job;
```

Note: Grouping done on Owner and Job expecting you have other values along with 'CEO'